# How to set the apache2.conf for same domain different directory?

Tags: debian, apache2

Environment: apache 2.4 + debian 9.
I have build a wordpress in directory  `/var/www/html/wp1`,setting on `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

`127.0.0.1/wp1` can show it.
I build another wordpress on `/home/material/wp2`,change setting  as below `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/material
<Directory /home/material>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

`127.0.0.1/wp2` can show it.
Now i want to combine the two setting to let `127.0.0.1/wp1` show wordpress on 
`/var/www/html/wp1`,and `127.0.0.1/wp2` show wordpress on `/home/material/wp2`,simply combining the two setting can't achieve my target.
How to write the proper setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things which are wrong or you shouldn't do.

In Debian the main configuration file is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` which includes other configuration files relative to the main directory `/etc/apache2`:

- site configurations from `sites-enabled/*.conf`
- generic configuration files from `conf-enabled/*.conf`
- module configurations `mods-enabled/*.load` and `mods-enabled/*.conf`

The *available* configuration files are in directories `sites-available`, `conf-available` and `mods-available` and to *enable* a configuration, you can use the commands `a2ensite`, `a2enconf` and `a2enmod` which symlinks them from `xxx-available` in `xxx-enabled`. To disable a configuration you would use `a2dissite`, `a2disconf` and `a2dismod`.

The first mistake is to edit the main configuration file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Instead you should have done this:

1. Disable (or edit) the default config with `a2dissite 000-default` (directory `sites-enabled` is now empty)
2. Create a new configuration like `sites-available/wordpress.conf` with the content of your configuration
3. Enable the new configuration with `a2ensite wordpress` which symlinks `wordpress.conf` in `sites-enabled`
4. Run `apachectl configtest` to see if you have syntax errors
5. Restart the server with `service apache2 restart` if the previous command was successful.

Your configuration has one syntax error and several mistakes:

- Instead of a closing `</VirtualHost>` you used `</VirtualHost *:80>`
- `Order deny,Allow` and `Allow from all` is [deprecated syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access) in Apache 2.4. You only need `Require all granted`.
- `ServerName` is missing. Have a look at the [VirtualHost examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

If you want to use port 80 for both sites, this could work as your new config `sites-available/wordpress.conf` (untested):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # set your host name/server name
    ServerName myservername

    # wp1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # wp2
    Alias /wp2 /home/material/wp2
    <Directory /home/material/wp2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Or even simpler: Move the `wp2` directory to `/var/www/html` and remove the lines for the second wordpress instance from the configuration.

And don't forget to restore your original `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.